# NSLog of AFNetworking POST data

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am making a POST request using AFNetwork. My AFNetwork folder contains AFNetworkActivityLogger. Does anyone know where I need to hack in order to NSLog the content that is being sent to the server? I need to make sure that what I think I am sending is indeed what is being sent. I tried a few things to no avail, including this:

```
    NSString *body = nil;
    if ([request HTTPBody]) 
    {
        body = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[request HTTPBody] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"REQUEST BODY: %@",body);
    }
```

Comment: This very much depends on what you are sending. Based on the information right now it seems you are utilizing REST-calls to the server. Are you using SOAP (POST/GET/DELETE) or REST(GET/DELETE)? REST does not "contain" a HTTPBody in the sense that the only "body" sent to the server contains headers. Not actual POST-data.

Comment: @AlexanderW in that case where would I add the NSLog? I am using google-cloud-endpoint:https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_ios

Comment: This also depends. As the code supplied not is enough for me to determine your procedure of building up your request object, i cannot say for sure. The `[request HTTPBody]` is only accessible after you have actually added your body to it. I think that you are probably building your request further up in the code snippet supplied. Since the body consists of a NSData object it cannot be read directly. Regarding Google cloud-endpoint i cannot help you, i'm sorry. I do not have sufficient knowledge of that API.